# Mass populating a new main.tf file from a CSV of resources?

Tags: azure, terraform, devops

I have thousands of resources in Azure, and it would take a very long time to go through and define a **resource** block in a main.tf file for each and every resource. I have created a CSV file with a sample set of the same type of resources, and only included columns for each of them that are required for the terraform resource.

What I would like to do is read from this CSV file, and output all of the resources in terraform resource blocks in a new main.tf file.

Is this possible? Are there better ways? I am more versed in PowerShell than Python.

I have successfully created a PowerShell script that can mass import terraform resources from a CSV, but in order to import resources, they need to exist in resource blocks :)

Comment: Please take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to Mass-populate a new main.tf file from a CSV of resources using Python and I was able to provision the requirement successfully.

To generate Terraform resource blocks from a CSV file using Python, you can use this approach to simplify the management of many resources in Terraform. The concept is similar to PowerShell, which you are more familiar with. Here's a general outline of how to do it using Python. I'll guide you through a simple example:

**Step1:**

Ensure your CSV file is structured in a way that each row represents a resource, and each column represents an attribute of that resource that you need in your Terraform configuration. For example:
**`resources.csv`**

```
name,location,resource_group
vkResource1,East US,myResourceGroup1
vkResource2,West US,myResourceGroup2
```

**Step 2:**

You'll use Python to read this CSV file, and for each row, generate a Terraform resource block with the attributes filled in from the CSV.

Below is a Python script example that reads a CSV file and generates Terraform resource blocks. This example assumes a very basic structure for demonstration purposes.

**`generate_tf.py`**

```
import csv

# Path to your CSV file
csv_file_path = 'resources.csv'  # Adjust this path as necessary

# Open the CSV file and read its contents
with open(csv_file_path, mode='r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    
    # Open the main.tf file for writing
    with open('main.tf', 'w') as tf_file:
        # Loop through each row in the CSV to create Terraform blocks
        for row in csv_reader:
            # Write the Terraform block for a resource group to the main.tf file
            tf_file.write(f'resource "azurerm_resource_group" "{row["name"]}" {{\n')
            tf_file.write(f'  name     = "{row["name"]}"\n')
            tf_file.write(f'  location = "{row["location"]}"\n')
            tf_file.write('}\n\n')  # Add an extra newline for spacing between blocks
```

now run the command

**`python generate_tf.py`**

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

[image]